# Black box over bracket when using \overbrace

Tags: overbrace

I'm using \overbace for some math formulas. At the begining everything works properly, but now when I compile file with an \overbrace I have some problem with the display of brackets.

For example, this line of code

```
$A'' = \langle Q', \Sigma, \delta', q_I', \overbrace{Q' \setminus F'}^{(F')^C}\rangle$
```

produces the following PDF:
[image: Result of \overbrace]

Why does it display that awful black box over the bracket?
I'm using TeX Live 2020

EDIT: This is the file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, italian]{babel}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    Se $A'$  è un DFA allora avremo che 
    $A'' = \langle Q', \Sigma, \delta', q_I', \overbrace{Q' \setminus F'}^{(F')^C}\rangle$.
    Si ha che $A''$ è un DFA e si ha che $sc(L'') = sc(L')$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: as always on the site: post a full but minimal example that others can test as is. Also specify which latex installation you are using. Unrelated `<>` are not the correct symbols here, use `\langle` and `\rangle`

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I don't understand what happened, but testing  whether there was a conflict between packages, I commented most packages that seemed unnecessary  to typeset your formula, and this solved the problem. Then I decommented one after the other, and the problem remained solved. *Unrelated*: `hyperref` should be loaded as the last package, with very few exceptions. Also, you don't have to load `latexsym` if you load `amsfonts`, nor `amsmath` if you load `mathtools`.

Comment: @MarcoMantovani Please show this information in your question and minimize your code example accordingly.

Comment: Ok, solved. Simply I move `\usepackage{fdsymbol}` as the last import before `\usepackage{hyperref}`

Comment: I assumed that the problem was bad font metrics (bounding boxes) for the fdsymbols fonts. I don't have any idea now, seeing how the ordering fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a *caveat*. Using `fdsymbol` changes all math symbols, using shapes that are not really compatible with Computer Modern. They're thought to accompany the [Fedra typeface](https://www.typotheque.com/fonts/fedra_serif_a).

Your problem arises because `fdsymbol` redefines `\underbrace` and `\overbrace`, but `mathtools` changes them again using some assumptions that don't hold when the symbol font is provided by `fdsymbol`.

So load `fdsymbol` after `mathtools` (assuming you want to load it to begin with).

Comment: If one can't change the load order of the `mathtools` package, e.g. b/c one is using an external document class, one can also restore the original `\overbrace` and `\underbrace` with `\let\underbrace\LaTeXunderbrace
\let\overbrace\LaTeXoverbrace`, as documented in the `mathtools` documentation.